# How to send mail after selecting text from select list using rules?

Tags: rules

In my content I have a select list text field. I have four options for that. While clicking only particular one in select list and giving click save. Then I want to generate mail to users.For example: I have select list fields like born, dead, live, none... while user selects born and goes to click save. I want to send a mail for administrator.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it "while user selects born and goes to click save". You can do it after the user has selected born and has clicked save.

Comment: Is your field named category and are you using taxonomy terms? OR did you just copy paste this example from somewhere?

Comment: What do you want the e-mail to say? Does it depend on what they selected?

Comment: So you just want the e-mail to say New litter was born, if they select new litter? and if they select something else, don't send anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(UPDATED)**

go to /admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add

1) **Name:** Give the rule whatever name you want.

2) **React on even:** (Under Node) Select **After Saving New Content**

**Restrict by type**: select **Cage Card Info**

Now you're taken to a new page

3) Under **Conditions**, click on Add Condition.

4) In the drop down, **select TEXT COMPARISON**

5) Click on the Blue Link that says **(DATA SELECTORS)**

6) **Look for your field**, if you named it "warnings", then look for **node:field-warnings**

then **highlight it, copy and paste it under Data Selector***

7) Under **Matching Text** put **New litter**

Then click SAVE

8) Under **Actions**, click add action

scroll all the way down, under system, select mail

9) Under **TO**, put **[site:mail]** OR **yourname@gmail.com** (if you don't have access to your websites e-mail inbox)

Then fill out the subject and message fields, click save.

You're done, now go and test it.

**Side Note 1**: 
I figured why the e-mail was not being set. I was trying namehere@gmail.com instead of putting admin@yourdomain.com as the websites admin e-mail in `/admin/config/system/site-information`

> "under Configuration/Site Information under "Site Details" you MUST
>   insert an email address from your domain, and then the email works."

**Side Note 2**: seems like e-mails get sent after running cron. So you wont see the e-mail until cron runs. See [Mail is sending after a cron run](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173515/mail-is-sending-after-running-the-cron)

Comment: Comments have been removed. Please don't use them for extended discussion; that is not the purpose of comments on Stack Exchange sites.