# sending mail for select list field

Tags: rules, emails

I have created a content type in which I have a field as *field_result* of type *select list* with options as;

1. pass
2. fail
3. hold
4. postpone

When user selects the *pass* from select list and update or create a content, email should be sent to all admin users and other users stating that result is pass. Following same thing to other select list options ie for fail,hold and postpone. So what exactly I need to do using rules?

Here event can be both like; user can save the new content also can update using this select list field. Whenever user selects, it should send an email according to corresponding select list option.

Can anyone help me please? I will be thankful to you. My problem is similar to [sending mail after checking a selected list in field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173412/sending-mail-after-checking-a-selected-list-in-fieldthis) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Do you have any mail service running which can send the emails? Rule should be straight forward. I suggest try out with simplest rule you can have with out any condition as simple as When a new content is created send email to admin(avoid looping in the first go.)

Comment: @arpitr: mail service? Smtp module i have used and i can send mail whenever i save the content this rule i created to test, but here my objective is to send email to all user when they select particular select list of field_result.

Comment: Completely understood your problem, just wanted to make sure you have a mail service in place that you have!

Comment: @arpitr: if your familiar with rules please lend me a hand to solve this issue.Thank you

Comment: Very similar to my answer in [here](http://example.com). Just create different rule for each option.

Comment: @No Sssweat: when i click it showing as This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.

Comment: Ooops [Try this one](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173519/code-modification/173538?noredirect=1)

Comment: @NoSssweat: do i need to create separate rules for each option like pass,fail,hold,postpone...there only one text they are considering.

Comment: actually I don't think you need multiple rules, you just need to "Add condition" of TEXT COMPARISON for each option, as long as you **DO NOT USE "ADD AND"** (so make a text comparison for pass, save that, then add another condition of text comparison for fail, and so on...)

Comment: under matching text do we need to add all the field label??like pass,fail,hold,postpone??

Comment: no, just one at a time.

Comment: thanks a lot, if it works than Zillion thanks to you......

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat: really appreciate ....it worked for me.):):):zillion thanks to u

Comment: @neethu, no problem, glad to help =)

Comment: @neethu One more thing: If you want to send mail to all admin users, then use `"send mail to all users of a role"` instead of using `"send mail"` as your action.

Comment: @NoSssweat: loads of thanks:):):):):):):well i want to send mail based on the  user-type role category.....

Comment: @neethu: on the next page, it will give you an option of which role you want to send the e-mail to, so just select the administrator role, so all admins will get the e-mail.

Comment: @NoSssweat: your awesome..):): i will follow as u suggested......

Answer (score 1):

Following rule should help you

```
{ "rules_send_email" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send Email After Save",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--send_email" : { "bundle" : "send_email" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "mail_to_users_of_role" : {
          "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } },
          "subject" : "Subject Test",
          "message" : "submittted value for Result field is [node:field-result]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above rule will trigger email when a new content will be added For update also clone this rule and change the event to "After updating existing content"

Comment: thank you so so much, but i am new to drupal and  i am not so good with rules.... and u told me to clone!!does it mean to  import this code????please elaborate ur answer it will be great full.

Comment: <strong>best would be to go through rules tutorial videos https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-rules?p=1157.</strong>

I meant two things
- Import this rule.
- Once you import this, you will get option to clone it, so basically there will be two rules after that.

Comment: :thanks for sharing ......i will watch those for better understanding.

Comment: I rarely downvote, instead I prefer to add some "constructive" critique ... (1) Are you sure you don't need a Rules Condition "Entity has field" (to ensure the field-result value IS available)? (2) no need to clone this rule (for update), just add "update" as a second Rules Event (so that the rule triggers for either event) (3) no matter which value is selected, the eMail is always the same (and includes the selected value). Why not use "conditional rules" module so that you can add a different eMail subject/msg for each value? Curious about your feedback ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens 

(1) Are you sure you don't need a Rules Condition "Entity has field" (to ensure the field-result value IS available)? Of course yes +1, but if you will go through the comments OP was having problem in sending mail to all users of a role(diff between send_mail and mail_to_users_of_role), but I agree the answer does not exactly solves the actual question.

Comment: (2) no need to clone this rule (for update), just add "update" as a second Rules Event (so that the rule triggers for either event) - I prefer to do it in two separate rules, so to have just one click needed to turn on/off any of two, its more of how you want to organise it, I do not see any functional impact.

Comment: (3) no matter which value is selected, the eMail is always the same (and includes the selected value). Why not use "conditional rules" module so that you can add a different eMail subject/msg for each value? I do not OP has specifically asked for email content to be conditional based on value. Its more of notifying all admins a content has been updated with new field value as '', that is how I assume it to be, in case email content was conditional I agree with you.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I totally understand your concerns, but the answer added here was not to give the exact solution but to give a kick start to OP. 

+1 for  "add some "constructive" critique"

Comment: @arpitr Merci (thank you) for your comments here, I see "your" points. Feel free to reuse any of my feedback here to further refine your answer should you want to do so (no credits needed).

Comment: Oeps, I forgot something ...